# VLJC imports not being recognized

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries, vlcj

I'm trying to use VLCJ for the first time and I downloaded the [dist](http://capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj-4/tutorials/installation) they have at their site's tutorial.
I unzipped the dist inside of my project's source folder, then went to my IDE (Netbeans) and went into Libraries and added all of the .jar files that were now laying in the src folder.

However, I still get the error about the IDE not recognizing these libraries.

```
package uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory does not exist
```

Furthermore, I'd like to know. If I share this code with someone who has never touched neither VLC nor VLCJ, will they be able to run the program with their IDE and see the video that its supposed to play? One of my concern's is that apparently the user needs to have VLC installed.

```
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory.MediaPlayerFactory;



public class Tower {


    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    }
```

Comment: Probably don't want to put those jars in your src directory

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm very new in java...where should they go?

Comment: So, I pulled the zip file from the link, uncompressed it, added `jna-5.2.0.jar`, `jna-platform-5.2.0.jar`, `vlcj-natives-4.1.0.jar`, `vlcj-4.1.0.jar` to the projects "libraries" and didn't have any issue with adding `import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory.*;`

Comment: *"where should they go?"* - Well, not in the `src` folder.  I tend to create a `lib` directory in the project directory (where `src` resides) and place the dependent Jars there, this will reduce possible issues with the build process - You may also want to take some time to learn what Maven is and how to use it

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is rather strange. The only part of the import being highlighted in red is uk.

I am able to declare MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory(); with no issues. And if I remove the import, then it tells me MediaPlayerFactory doesnt exist.

So it is recognizing the class, but the uk part seems to be giving it issues

Comment: Will it compile?

Comment: nope


I'm starting with maven now...seems to be rather similar to the package.json from angular apps which im more used to.